# How to configure JIRA API for allowed for cross-origin HTTP request

Tags: angularjs, http, cors, jira-rest-api

I want to integrate my app with JIRA, so when I send request to JIRA server its returns error call '**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://*********/rest/api/2/project. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**'

This is my code

```
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://***********/rest/api/2/project",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*******',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia,Authorization'
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
        console.log(response.statusText);
    });

};
```

Comment: Why are you adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers to a request? Why are you adding a `Content-Type` to a GET request?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I try to call from client side so I got this error.So then I call API through back end.Now issue was fixed.